# How to loop through all cells of a column and retrieve values

Tags: c#, datagridview

I can't seem to access the actual values in my column; My values for each row end up all being the same and actual row count. I can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my current method:

```
  private string converter() {
   string binaryString = string.Empty;
   int cellValue = 0;
   int colIndex = 3;
   foreach(DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
       cellValue = (int) row.Cells[colIndex].Value;
       binaryString = parseString(cellValue);
      }
     return binaryString;
    }
```

Comment: That won't work as .Cells is not a property of DataRow

Comment: That's not what I want but thanks anyway.

Comment: edit your question and try to explain with a drawing in text what you are trying to do..

Comment: I am trying to iterate through a DataGridView. I want to iterate through all of the rows of a particular column. I want to take each row's value and pass it into a function and assign that result to a string. I want to then return this string for each iteration. If there are 100 rows, I want 100 unique Strings.

Comment: The posted code will only return the LAST string. The code is NOT saving the string with each iteration.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am wondering how to avoid that.

Comment: The answer @Clay07g supplied solves this. Return a list of strings instead of a single string,

Comment: How would I iterate through to return each element of he list? I am very new to C#, as you could tell

Comment: You are already iterating through the rows, but you only return ONE string… which string do you want to return? If you want to get ALL the strings in each row at cell `colIndex`, then you would be returning more than ONE string. If this is the case then you can return either ONE big string, or a list of strings. Example using Clay07g’s answer, if there are 100 rows, then `converter` will return a list of 100 strings.

Comment: What if I wanted to populate 100 unique rows with each string?

Comment: Then loop through the list of strings and add each string to a new row.

Comment: Of type Data Row?

Comment: You are going to have to clarify WHAT you are trying to do. A `DataRow` is a row in a `DataTable`. The row can have more than one item (columns), one of those items/columns could be the string. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion . I am trying to take these 100 unique strings and populate 100 different rows with these 100 strings in a DataGridView

Comment: Ok… break that problem down to two parts. Part one, get a list of “100 unique strings”. The posted answer does this. Part two, loop through this list of unique strings and “populate 100 different rows”. I am guessing there is more to this.

Comment: There is another column on my DataGridView table that I am going to populate with these strings

Comment: Hmmm, so you want to have the same value in two different columns in the same datagridview? Can you describe what the overall goal is? This may help avoid playing twenty questions.

Comment: So I have four columns. One column is empty but I am using the integer values of the column over to populate this empty column. The values will be the string representation of my function. So say column A is 128 I want column B to be 10000000 and if the next row of A is 8, I want the next row of B to be 1000

Comment: Then what is the function? If column “A” is 128 then column “B” is 10000000?… what is the function doing with 128 to get 10000000? Assuming you are using a `DataTable`, it sounds like a `DataColumn.Epression` may be a better approach. This columns `Expression` could be your function, and it will update automatically, there will be no need to loop through the cells. Again, what is this function doing?

Comment: It's converting the integer value to a binary string.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You are replacing the value of "binaryString" in each loop duration.</s>

I'm not sure what your goal is, but perhaps this what you meant:

```
binaryString += parseString(cellValue);
```

Notice the **+=**

**Edit - Another Approach?**

Perhaps you want each value in a column to be converted? Try this, then.

```
private List<String> converter() 
{
   List<String> binaryStrings = new List<String>();
   int cellValue = 0;
   int colIndex = 3;
   foreach(DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
       cellValue = (int) row.Cells[colIndex].Value;
       binaryStrings.Add(parseString(cellValue));
   }
   return binaryStrings;
}
```

This gives you a list of converted strings. One string per row.

Comment: += will just concatenate a String

Comment: I honestly don't know what you're trying to accomplish. I've put in another approach in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am just trying to loop through the rows of a column and get the integer values. Once I get those values (int), I am passing each value to the parser method. I am not sure a List would work

Comment: Do you mean my original code or your List recommendation?

Comment: Your original code. It gets every value in a column, passes it to your parser method. However, every time you do 'binaryString = parseString(cellValue);', you **overwrite** the previous value of binaryString.

Comment: But since binaryString is a Stirng, if I do a += operation, I am just adding to the String to make one long String. I would want a new String instance for each row.

Comment: Then use my second solution. It gives you a list of strings.

Comment: It only gives a list if I iterate through it, which is not what I want to do. I just want to return the string value

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `DataTable` I do not think you can make an `Expression` to convert a base 10 number to a binary string representation. However it is possible to add the binary string to the cell whenever a `DataRow` changes. If a `DataRow` changes in the `DataTable`, then the code can do the conversion of the base 10 value to a binary string representation and add the string to the proper cell.

In order to achieve this, the code needs to register the `RowChanged` event BEFORE the `DataTable` is filled. In addition, since a value is changed in the `RowChanged` event, it is necessary to turn off this event when the code adds the binary string to the table. This will prevent an obvious infinite loop, which would keep calling itself every time the binary string is added to the row.

You will need to change the names to match your requirements. Below is the line needed to register the `RowChanged` event with the `DataTable`. Note you need to set this line BEFORE you fill the table with data.

```
gridTable.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed);
```

Then all we need is this `Row_Changed` method. NOTE, the event is unregistered from the `DataTable` to avoid an infinite loop.

```
private static void Row_Changed(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e) {
  gridTable.RowChanged -= new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed);
  DataRow dr = e.Row;
  int base10 = (int)dr["Base10"];
  string binary = Convert.ToString(base10, 2);
  dr["Binary"] = binary;
  gridTable.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed);
}
```

I am guessing there may be other ways to accomplish this, the goal here was to avoid having to loop through the grid to set the binary strings. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i was looking for a solution to your problem...
here i what i came with..

works here.

```
   foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    if(column.Name == "wanted column name")
                    {
                        for(int iRow = 0; iRow < dataGridView1.RowCount; iRow++)
                        {
                            string data = (string)dataGridView1[column.Index, iRow].Value;
                            //Do something with data
                        }

                    }

                }
```